# How to setup Firebase in Flutter for multiple environments pointing to different projects?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase

I have configured Firebase using Flutter fire CLI it has created a firebase_options file.

I have multiple environments, each environment needs to have a different firebase project.
Other answers indicate we can add the configuration via Android and iOS directories from our flutter project, is that the old way to do it?
can we have multiple firebase_options files instead?
what is the way to do it when we use Flutter fire CLI approach?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-flavors-for-firebase-apps/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think you can provide a name for the firebase app next to option, could that be used to make more than a firebase instance? like this

```
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
        name: 'appOne',
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions1.currentPlatform,
      );
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
        name: 'appTwo',
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions2.currentPlatform,
      );
```